# Search/Filtering algorithm suggestion

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, query-optimization

Need suggestion on algorithm for a application which needs to store a set of numbers (mostly random - but limited set) and figure out if a given number is present in the set.
Emphasis on minimum memory footprint.

Comment: What's the range of numbers?

Comment: I would suggest using a `hashset` or some kind of bitmask

Comment: Range is 32-bit unsigned integers

Comment: A crit-bit tree then perhaps, they have some of the lowest overhead per item in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages have some kind of set data structure implemented in the standard library. Maybe check out those and see if they fulfill your needs.